# Scale react website down as viewport shrinks

Tags: reactjs

I would like to know how I can scale down my react website as the window size / viewport gets smaller. I know how I can dynamically change the HTML based on the viewport, but most websites, for the smaller ranges of window sizes, 'scale the website down' as in the video attached. How can I achieve the same effect?

https://www.veed.io/view/377cdfa6-02bd-48ea-a204-79a125dbb77c?panel=share